When is the Cartan matrix of a graph positive semi-definite?
Suppose
$$ C = 2I - A $$
where $I$ is the diagonal matrix and $A$ the adjacency matrix of a graph ($C$ is the Cartan matrix of the graph). Suppose that for all vectors $v$ with entries non-negative integers
$$ Cv \geq 0 \quad \text{(each entry is non-negative)}. $$
Does it follow that $C$ is positive semi-definite?

By the given condition, every column of $C$ is nonnegative. Thus all off-diagonal elements of $C$ are zero. Hence $C$ is a nonnegative diagonal matrix, which is positive semidefinite.
